# client side code to get the access token not working

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am using client side authenticantion code to get an acess token from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/ (without JS SDK) to one of the pages for which I am a manager. I have cahnged the App id and the graph url (https://graph.facebook.com/page_id) to get the access token. But when I am running the script I get an error in the FB page. MY url reads (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=app_id&redirect_uri=file:///C:/work/dashboard/FBGraph.html&response_type=token). Please advise.

Thanks,
Madhura

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are redirecting to a local file on your hard disk, redirect_uri=**file:///C:/work/dashboard/FBGraph.html** you need to redirect to a real web URL which is related to the web URL listed for your app.

Comment: I tried using the following url https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=app_id&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/?ref=tn_tnmn#!/app_name?sk=messages_inbox&response_type=token.I am redirected to https://www.facebook.com/app_name?sk=messages_inbox&response_type=token but still do not get the access token. Am I missing any privileges?